# Will installing Continuous Integration disturb other sites on server

Tags: php, continuous-integration, centos

I have many php sites running on my VPS. I want to build one more Site but with continuous integration process . Now i read the docs and i think i need to install many things for that.

So i want to know will my other sites be affected or i can keep other sites separate. and use continuous integration server Jenkins or Hudson only for one site. is it possible.

Is there any book which can guide me in building that sort of project.

Comment: Hey, did you manage to get it up and running? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using a VPS, you could probably **clone** your current setup.

In the clone, setup the CI and check that nothing broke in the other sites. After you think you're done, either

- a) **use the newly created clone as "main server"** and redirect all traffic there, with the intent to later on remove the first "clone" (what you have currently). This requires that all changes you do to your main server after you cloned the VPS, you apply to the clone as well.
- or b) **apply all steps you took to guarantee the cloned server works** 100%, on the main server. This requires that you document each change to the cloned server.

If it's not a huge deal that your current site goes down for a while (like a hobby site) then I would just go for it. Just read docs & tutorials before you start, to find out about eventual pitfalls.

*(This reasoning could be applied to all major changes of your server, the CI-example should be quite safe to perform since, last time I tried, Hudson was only one file large...)*